# Missile velocity

Tags: rocket-science

How is speed of a missile system controlled. can it be controlled during the flight, or it is dependent on initial launch velocity? Will the variable mass equations apply to it?

Comment: not 100% sure, but generally missiles will have motors like a rocket... so speed is not just due to launch